# ESP8266 disconnecting after some weeks

Tags: c++, arduino, wifi, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to keep ESP8266 connected to my WiFi network forever.

Is this possible?

So far it is working only for some weeks and then disconnects from the router. How can I fix it? Maybe a reboot?
Could it be related to Lease Time or another setting in the router?

Comment: When it disconnects does it reconnect?

Comment: No it doesn't, it remains disconnected

Comment: Can you program it to reconnect when it becomes disconnected?

Comment: I already tried, in theory it reboots when disconnected, but it doesn't.
How can I keep it connected forever? Is there a router setting?

Comment: I think you should make it so it reconnects automatically. What would happen if someone tripped over your router's power cord? Or if a storm knocked out your power for a moment? Or if the neighbour used a faulty microwave that interfered with the wi-fi?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to electronic failure, in other words, there may be overheating, poor contact of the components, a check in the project hardware and eliminate the possibility of a hardware error.

Comment: This happens periodically every two weeks I think, can't it be related to something in the router configs?

Comment: what is the brand and model of the router?

Comment: It's a Technicolor AGHP